# SEO - carve up one dynamic file with params into fixed-name files

Tags: seo

So I've got an existing real estate site. All the searches go through one php file, ie: sales_search.php?city=boston&br=4

If I create the following files:

boston-1-br.php
boston.2-br.php
boston-3-br.php
boston-4-br.php
brookline-1-br.php
brookline-2-br.php
brookline-3-br.php
brookline-4-br.php
etc…

I would then use these in place of the sales_search?city=XXX&br=NNN wherever possible and only use sales_search.php for 'advanced' searches. These new files are still dynamic as they pull content from a database.

Would this help the rankings? Hurt them? Waste of time? Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they'll help, or hurt rankings. The content on the page is far more important. What is the similarity of the content between these pages? When pages are named very similar to each other it can trigger a flag to make the spider look for doorway pages. If the content is varied enough you have little to worry about.

Have you considered using a url rewriter and turning them into .htm files? There have been a lot of arguments about it, but I have personally noticed .htm files do better than .php